# Is there a sum o a completed function in excel?

Tags: excel, sum

I need to calculate this sum in excel and i don't want go throw it all, is there any function i can use that do it for me?

[image: the sum function]
the Pn is Column P and n is the row from 1 to 206

Comment: Show some data and expected output, we need cell references.

Comment: "i don't want go throw it all"???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am going to assume the `Pn` is Column `P` and `n` is the row from 1 to 206

```
=SUMPRODUCT((P1:P206-P208)^2)
```

Comment: it's exactly what i need thank you very much